# Execl Permission Denied

Tags: c, linux, execl

Creating a producer/consumer system. The producer is meant to call the consumer but i am getting the error

```
execl failed for producer: Permission denied
```

Here is the call:

```
if (execl("/home/aaron/Documents/Programming/c/producerAsignment",   
          "runConsumer", NULL) == -1) {

     perror("execl failed for producer");
     exit(3);
}
```

I have tried putting the executable file into the same directory as the program calling it but that made no difference.

```
ls -l /home/aaron/Documents/Programming/c/producerAsignment 
...
-rwxrwxr-x 1 aaron aaron 8760 Jan 10 22:28 runConsumer 
...
```

Comment: type `ls -l /home/aaron/Documents/Programming/c/producerAsignment` in bash and post the output

Comment: aaron@aaron:~$ ls -l /home/aaron/Documents/Programming/c/producerAsignment
total 60
drwxrwxr-x 3 aaron aaron  4096 Dec 16 13:49 build
drwxrwxr-x 3 aaron aaron  4096 Dec 16 13:49 dist
-rw-rw-r-- 1 aaron aaron  3482 Nov 23 22:56 Makefile
drwxrwxr-x 3 aaron aaron  4096 Nov 23 22:56 nbproject
-rw-rw-r-- 1 aaron aaron  3782 Jan 10 23:00 produce.c
-rwxrwxr-x 1 aaron aaron 13484 Jan 10 22:53 run
-rwxrwxr-x 1 aaron aaron  8760 Jan 10 22:28 runConsumer
-rwxrwxr-x 1 aaron aaron  9050 Dec  7 09:32 yellow

Comment: Are you giving the name of a directory? See this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19414460/for-the-following-c-program-execl-returns-1-signifying-a-permission-denied-er

Comment: The first argument of execl is the path to the executable.

Answer (score 4):

Ok, it turns out that the file you are trying to execute is actually a directory (see letter "d" at the beginning of the `ls` command output). You cannot execute directories. Only files with the execute permission.

Comment: Thanks very much! Just spotted that! Have a nice day!